# Is necessary to restart node in every deploy to Azure Web App?

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, azure-devops, nuxt.js

I build and deployed a Vue/nuxt web app to Azure Web App by configuring Azure DevOps build and release pipelines.

The app runs on top of node and Express configuration. I start the app on the server by typing: `npm run start` on Kudu's CMD. Then the `start` script is set in the `package.json` file to launch the command: `node server/index.js`.

On the other hand, the build pipeline is configured to trigger a new build of the app (`npm run build`) when a new commit occurs and then the release pipeline catches the output and deploys it to Azure by Zip Deploy mechanism ("Azure App Service deploy" task).

So far I found not in the need to restart neither the Azure Web App nor the node process to update the app. In some ocassion I did found some strange error behaviour I solved by killing the process and restarting all over again.

In an official and proper way manner should I do this every time a new build is released? And how can I do it? I can gues on how to restart node via post deployment actions but what about killing the process? I must kill otherwise the new process port number will collide with the running one.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there exists some circumstances under which an application deployment might result in a restart. 
See [Deployment vs. runtime issues](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues#deployments-and-web-app-restarts%22), `App Service` deploys files to the `wwwroot` folder. It never **directly** restarts your app.

So i think it's necessary when your changes in code do not start to work in your application, but if it works well when sometimes the restart occurs, you don't need to do the restart manually. Also, if you want to restart the app service, you can try [Azure App Service Manage Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops) or restart it in Azure web portal.